# Admin page won't load anymore after upgrade to Magento 2.3.3 (404 not found)

Tags: magento2.3.3

In magento2.3.3 - after upgrade, Admin page not loading anymore.....

Comment: Can you please update more info ?

Comment: can you check you pub/static in admin and frontend folder.?